# Hibernate criteria right outer join resulting list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm doing a right outer join of Cats with Owners, how can i get as a result a list of Owners?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cats.class);
List<Owners> list= criteria.createCriteria("owner",JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

A cat has one owner but an owner can have many cats.

Edit:

The reason of this, is to be able to add restrictions to the criteria based on more relations, let me elaborate this.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cats.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("breed.pkBreed")).add(Restrictions.ne(breed.desc,"Egyptian cat")));
List<Owners> list= criteria.createCriteria("owner",JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

In this case, i am retrieving all the non Egyptian cats owners and all the cats owners with currently no breed assigned, and this is my exact scenario, but with different data.

I know it sounds weird, but this is the exact query for my requirement.

Also, even if i don't transform the list data, i have no clue of what's in it, so i can iterate in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of headaches with the alias, i got what i wanted =)

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cats.class,"c");
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("breed.pkBreed"));
criteria.createCriteria("owner","o",JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq(c.breed.desc,"Egyptian cat"))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("o.pkOwner").as("pkOwner"))
        .add(Projections.property("o.name").as("name"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Owners.class));
List<Owners> list=criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are saying "A cat has one owner but an owner can have many cats." how can you get list of owners, if u want list of owner so not need to do outer join or any other joins just provide id's of owners or get all owners without any where condition.